# Include C++ mfc object library in multiple solutions?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, linker, dependencies

I have an object file library that exists as a standalone VC++ solution. I have a number of other completely separate VC++ solutions, and I would like some of them to utilise the classes included in this library.

However, since they are in the same solution, I cannot seem to add them as a dependency. I have attempted to investigate so-called "linker" dependencies but can't get it to work.

Does anyone know of a standard, modern efficient way to do this. Eventually my plan is to conglomerate these projects into a single solution as I believe they should be, but that is not something I have the time to deal with right now.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing terms project and solution. Generally speaking, solution is a collection of projects, with specified dependencies between them.

Library should be a project (possibly dependent on another projects), but not a solution. If you would like to include your library in another solutions, simplest way to do that would be to add project for library (and any dependent projects) to solutions you would like to add them by right clicking on solution->add->add existing project->add your project. This will ensure library will be compiled as part of solution.

You would need to set dependencies between projects (in your solution), and add include/linker path for the library to any projects using it within the solution.

Comment: No, how I've currently got the library is in a solution by itself. I had been advised that I add the project to multiple solutions, but I didn't know if the fact that the library was already its own solution would pose a problem. Your answer suggests that it won't pose a problem, so I'll go ahead and give that a go. Cheers!

Comment: @user1014679 The fact it is in its own solution without any dependencies only simplifies adding it. Solution only manages collection of projects and relationship between them, it is ok to add same project to multiple solutions - they won't affect each other.

Comment: I have attempted to add the project following the instructions here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235627.aspx, however, I am still getting unresolved external symbol errors. Do you know if there is anything else I need to do?

Comment: @user1014679 Sorry, but I don't see how the link you provided is of any relevance to the question you asked. All you need to do is to add your already existing library project to solution containing projects that need to use it, and specify include/link path in projects that use the library, while the link you provided describes how to create new library and hence is irrelevant.

Comment: The link I provided describes the process you said further down - how to specify include/link paths. I was providing the link so you can see the process that I followed to do that (which is the same as you have just described). The problem is that that has not worked for me.